# How Can I Retrieve The Earliest Date and Status Per Each Distinct ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, filter, min

I have been trying to write a query to perfect this instance but cant seem to do the trick because I am still receiving duplicated. Hoping I can get help how to fix this issue.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
1.Client
1.ID
1.Thing
1.Status
MIN(1.StatusDate) as 'statdate'

FROM
SAMPLE 1

WHERE
[]

GROUP BY
1.Client
1.ID
1.Thing
1.status
```

My output is as follows

```
Client   Id   Thing   Status   Statdate
CompanyA  123   Thing1   Approved   12/9/2019
CompanyA  123   Thing1   Denied   12/6/2019
```

So although the query is doing what I asked and showing the mininmum status date per status, I want only the first status date. I have about 30k rows to filter through so whatever does not run overload the query and have it not run. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (SELECT s.*, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY statdate) as seqnum
      FROM SAMPLE s
      WHERE []
     ) s
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

This returns the first row for each id.

Comment: I want the first row for each ID, not client. How would I utilize the query above to do that? Sorry I am very new to SQL and the above is a little confusing for me.

Comment: Change the partition to be in the ID not the client then, @Ziegler199 . Thought a non-unique ID seems like an odd design choice.

Answer (score 0):

Use whichever of these you feel more comfortable with/understand:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM 
  (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY statusdate) as rn
    FROM sample 
    WHERE ...
  ) x
WHERE rn = 1
```

The way that one works is to number all rows sequentially in order of StatusDate, restarting the numbering from 1 every time ID changes. If you thus collect all the number 1's togetyher you have your set of "first records"

Or can coordinate a MIN:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM 
  sample s
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT ID, MIN(statusDate) as minDate FROM sample WHERE ... GROUP BY ID) mins
  ON s.ID = mins.ID and s.StatusDate = mins.MinDate
WHERE
  ...
```

This one prepares a list of all the ID and the min date, then joins it back to the main table. You thus get all the data back that was lost during the grouping operation; you cannot simultaneously "keep data" and "throw away data" during a group; if you group by more than just ID, you get more groups (as you have found). If you only group by ID you lose the other columns. There isn't any way to say "GROUP BY id, AND take the MIN date, AND also take all the other data from the same row as the min date" without doing a "group by id, take min date, then join this data set back to the main dataset to get the other data for that min date". If you try and do it all in a single grouping you'll fail because you either have to group by more columns, or use aggregating functions for the other data in the SELECT, which mixes your data up; when groups are done, the concept of "other data from the same row" is gone

Be aware that this can return duplicate rows if two records have identical min dates. The ROW_NUMBER form doesn't return duplicated records but if two records have the same minimum StatusDate then which one you'll get is random. To force a specific one, ORDER BY more stuff so you can be sure which will end up with 1